# change color of extra characters in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

How can I change the color only of extra letters when typing in UITextField in Swift and return the color back when deleting?
I was able only to change color of all letters, when exceeding the limit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var inputLimitField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var characterCountLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        characterCountLabel.text = "10/10"
        inputLimitField.delegate = self

    }
    
    func checkRemainingChars() {
        let allowedChars = 10
        let charsInTextView = -(inputLimitField.text?.count ?? 0)
        let remainingChars = allowedChars + charsInTextView
        characterCountLabel.textColor = .black
        inputLimitField.textColor = .black
        inputLimitField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray3.cgColor
        if remainingChars < 0 {
            characterCountLabel.textColor = .red
            inputLimitField.textColor = .red
            inputLimitField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            inputLimitField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
            inputLimitField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        }
        characterCountLabel.text = ("\(String(remainingChars))/10")
    }
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        checkRemainingChars()
    }
}
```

this is what I expected to get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkSRW.png)

and this is what I really get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQOok.png)

p.s. also I can't put a letter counter in the corner through TF's border, because there is a mistake when I import Material Components: `No such module 'MaterialComponents'`

Comment: You need to use `NSAttributedString` to color only some letters. Then use `yourTextField.attributedText` to set it/retrieve it. With `String`/`yourTextField.text`, it's not possible, because it's just a list of letters, there is no "render" effects like colors, while `NSAttributedString` gives that possibility. Note, it can then also add others effects for characters: font (then bold/italic/size), underline, etc.

Comment: You already had the same topic some 8 hours ago.  Hint: `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: Hint 2: if let text = inputLimitField.text {
 let allowedText = text.prefix(allowedChars)
}

Comment: Hint 3: let notAllowedText = text.suffix(text.count - allowedChars)